# How to derive the simplest forms of $\sum{\binom{n}{i} \times 2^{n-i}}$ and $\sum{i \times \binom{n}{i} \times 2^{n-i}}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How can we derive these two equations 
 $\sum{\binom{n}{i} \times 2^{n-i}}=3^{n}$ 
 $\sum{i \times \binom{n}{i} \times 2^{n-i}} = n \times 3^{n-1}$

The second equation can be related to the following problem:

**You have $n$ balls and you can color each ball red, green, or blue. There are $3^n$ possible ways to color the balls. Among all possible ways, how many times we can get a ball of the color red. 
 If we select $i$ balls from $n$ balls and color them red and color the remaining balls either blue or green, we can get ${i \times \binom{n}{i} \times 2^{n-i}}$ red balls for all possible ways selecting $i$ red balls each time.**

How can we derive the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is immediate, by binomial expansion of $(2+1)^n$.

For the second, use

$$i\binom ni=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}.$$